# Using Test-Connection in powershell one line script to return directory content

Tags: c#, powershell

I originally wrote a script that takes an input of computer names via a text file and then checks the name of a subfolder in a set of paths for each name.  The script works great as is, but I wanted to add a check to only check computers that were online.  Every method of `Test-Connection` that I have tried ends up with the wrong value (or excess values) being passed into my `$_` variable in the path name.

The reason that I am trying to keep this as a one line script is to avoid having to change the PowerShell execution policies (this will be run on various machines, not the same one each time).

Below is my code as currently written.  I have thought about simply converting it into C#, and was wondering if anyone could think of any negatives by doing this?

```
Get-Content c:\temp\serverlist.txt |
  Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},
                @{Name='PROD XP Version';Expression={
                  Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$_\c$\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram",
                    "\\$_\c$\Program Files\MyProgam",
                    "\\$_\c$\Program Files (x86)\MyProgramTestFolder",
                    "\\$_\c$\Program Files\MyProgramTestFolder"
                }} > c:\temp\testVersions.txt
```

**Edit:** The code with the closest attempt I have had is:

```
Test-Connection -Count 1 -ComputerName (Get-Content C:\temp\serverlist.txt) |
  Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},
                @{Name='PROD XP Version';Expression={
                  Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$_\c$\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram",
                    "\\$_\c$\Program Files\MyProgam",
                    "\\$_\c$\Program Files (x86)\MyProgramTestFolder",
                    "\\$_\c$\Program Files\MyProgramTestFolder"
                }} > c:\temp\testVersions.txt
```

This works for listing the NAME properly, but passes a long string of data into `$_` for when it checks the paths.  I tried to change `$_` to `$_.address` in the path, but it has no impact.

Without using `.address` I'm getting `\\BEN-ACH-LAP\root\cimv2:Win32_PingStatus.Address="BEN-ACH-LAP",BufferSize=...` for my first computer name, which is why the path isn't working properly, because clearly, that isn't a valid PC name.

Comment: Sorry about that - clarified some and added the second code block.

Comment: Use the `-Quiet` switch for `Test-Connection`. Then you can use the True or False returned with an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter your list of host for those that are available on the network. To do this you need to run `Test-Connection` in a `Where-Object` filter:

```
Get-Content c:\temp\serverlist.txt |
  Where-Object { Test-Connection -Computer $_ -Count 1 -Quiet } |
  Select-Object ...
```

This will pass only those hostnames/addresses to `Select-Object` that responded to the ICMP request.

Comment: I've confirmed that it should `just work` with your original code as well, OP.  Simply remove your Test-connection statement and replace it with Ansgar's.

Comment: Absolutely perfect and what I was looking for - THANK YOU!!!!!!!

Both of you - That is exactly what I did, Fox